# Adding 'at' command to Raspbian

Tags: raspbian, bash

I want to be able to use the `at` command to run programs outside of cron. I see that it is missing from the listed BASH commands.

How can I add it?

Answer (score 7):

It shouldn't be much more than:

```
sudo apt-get install at
```

Comment: The package doesn't exist in raspbian 10 (buster)

Answer (score 1):

In general, when looking for a package to install when you know the name of the package - or part of the name, you can try this:

```bsh
apt-cache search XXXX
```

Where "XXXX" is the package name as best you know it.

In the case of `at` this isn't particularly helpful because many packages will match. But if you know the complete name of the package, you can proceed as follows:

```
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install at
```

The `update` and `upgrade` steps will help ensure you get the currently released packages if you've not installed any packages recently.

Comment: The package doesn't exist in raspbian 10 (buster)

Comment: @EdwardNedHarvey: ? It does exist - Why do you post misinformation?